# jquery show-option slide-down function in checkbox title doesnt work behind first "call"

Tags: jquery, checkbox, slidedown

My script works on the first use in my table.
But on the second use, the slideDown effect does not work.

This is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#show-option" ).tooltip({
                show: {
                    effect: "slideDown",
                    delay: 100
                }
            });
            $( "#hide-option" ).tooltip({
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    delay: 250
                }
            });
            $( "#open-event" ).tooltip({
                show: null,
                position: {
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left bottom"
                },
                open: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, "fast" );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And here is an example of how i use it.

```
                <input type="checkbox" value="NPC bootet nicht mehr" /> <a id="show-option" title="PLED noch an?&#10;Micom Reset erfolglos?&#10;Piept&ouml;ne?"> NPC bootet nicht mehr</a>
```

These lines are working very well, But only the first of my 400 checkboxes are working with the slide effect. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you have more than 400 check-boxes and the same count of `<a>`(anchor) elements?

Comment: No, there are more than 400 check-boxes, but only 150-200 has tis anchor elements.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just wanted to know if you have more than one anchor. So, your problem is connected to you are using the same `id` for all anchors. You should pay attention on it `ID must be unique`. Solution: Use `class` instead like rm-vanda wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are using ID's instead of classes ---

If you have 400 checkboxes, jQuery will only find the first one with the  ID you specified.

Therefore, change the ID to a class:

```
<a class="show-option"> [...]
```

and

```
 $( ".show-option" ).tooltip({
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It works great!
These change from ID to class was impressive for me!

Thanks rm-vanda for your help.

Comment: No problem, any time! And welcome to Stack Overflow ! -- Don't forget to mark the answer as correct !